# Android: Информация по работе с XAMPP

Tags: xampp, android, php, java, mysql

Нужно сделать постоянное соединение приложения с сайтом(на PHP).

Вроде,это можно сделать через сервер **XAMPP**, или **Socket(php)**, но информации ни по том ни потом нету, хоть бы один простой пример **real-time** приложений на этих вещах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://paw-android.fun2code.de/

вообще нагуглить можно. все. из технологий есть еще long pooling и websocket